# How do I get the day of week given a date?

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, weekday

I want to find out the following:
given a date (`datetime` object), what is the corresponding day of the week?

For instance, Sunday is the first day, Monday: second day.. and so on

And then if the input is something like today's date.

### Example

```
>>> today = datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 20)
>>> today.get_weekday()  # what I look for
```

The output is maybe `6` (since it's Friday)

Answer (score 1384, accepted):

Use `weekday()`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.today()
datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 23, 23, 24, 55, 173504)
>>> datetime.datetime.today().weekday()
4
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.weekday):

> Return the day of the week as an integer, where Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6.

Comment: One important thing to note is that in JavaScript 0 = Sunday, Python starts with 0 = Monday.  Something that I ran into, front-end vs back-end..

Comment: If you'd like Sunday to be day 0: `int(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%w'))`

Comment: To start from 1, we can use isoweekday in place of weekday; 1 = Monday

Comment: What about `.strftime('%A')` [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) to get a weekday name.

Comment: Who in their right mind would think the week starts at Sunday. Of course it starts at Saturday xD

Comment: instead of .weekday() try isoweekday()

Comment: date.isoweekday() does start on sunday

Answer (score 399):

If you'd like to have the date in the language of your current locale:

```
from datetime import date
import calendar
my_date = date.today()
calendar.day_name[my_date.weekday()]  #'Wednesday'
```

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.day_name

Comment: This seems to be the best answer to generate an English, day-of-week date. I'm guessing it's not upvoted more simply because the answer is ~1 month old, while the question is ~3 years old.

Comment: I find it much more effective to just do `my_date.strftime('%A')`

Comment: @NathanTew 1) is "my_date" a variable? 2) can this be used in a query/aggregation? I want to count the average number of meals ordered on mondays/tuesdays/wednesdays. Each order is on a new line, and just like this question, the weekday has to be retrieved from the data-time column of the csv file that we've just uploaded to elasticsearch.

Answer (score 241):

If you'd like to have the date in the language of your current locale:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now().strftime('%A')
'Wednesday'
>>> datetime.now().strftime('%a')
'Wed'
```

Read more:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 117):

Use [`date.weekday()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday) when Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6

or

[`date.isoweekday()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoweekday) when Monday is 1 and Sunday is 7

Comment: Because the op asked with regards to a `datetime` object (not a `date` object) I’d like to mention that the `datetime` class sports the same [`weekday()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.weekday) and [`isoweekday()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoweekday) methods.

Answer (score 55):

I solved this for a CodeChef [question](http://www.codechef.com/TCTR2012/problems/NOPC10/**).

```
import datetime
dt = '21/03/2012'
day, month, year = (int(x) for x in dt.split('/'))    
ans = datetime.date(year, month, day)
print (ans.strftime("%A"))
```

Answer (score 36):

A solution whithout imports for dates after 1700/1/1

```
def weekDay(year, month, day):
    offset = [0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334]
    week   = ['Sunday', 
              'Monday', 
              'Tuesday', 
              'Wednesday', 
              'Thursday',  
              'Friday', 
              'Saturday']
    afterFeb = 1
    if month > 2: afterFeb = 0
    aux = year - 1700 - afterFeb
    # dayOfWeek for 1700/1/1 = 5, Friday
    dayOfWeek  = 5
    # partial sum of days betweem current date and 1700/1/1
    dayOfWeek += (aux + afterFeb) * 365                  
    # leap year correction    
    dayOfWeek += aux / 4 - aux / 100 + (aux + 100) / 400     
    # sum monthly and day offsets
    dayOfWeek += offset[month - 1] + (day - 1)               
    dayOfWeek %= 7
    return dayOfWeek, week[dayOfWeek]

print weekDay(2013, 6, 15) == (6, 'Saturday')
print weekDay(1969, 7, 20) == (0, 'Sunday')
print weekDay(1945, 4, 30) == (1, 'Monday')
print weekDay(1900, 1, 1)  == (1, 'Monday')
print weekDay(1789, 7, 14) == (2, 'Tuesday')
```

Comment: why do we need to do aux+100 / 400 instead of aux/400 can you please explain

Comment: python3: just change all '/' with '//' in the function above and it will work like a charm.

Comment: @himanshu219 Because there's an exception from the leap year rule every 400 years, and `aux` was derived from `year -1700`, so we need to add 100 to make it a multiple of 400. For example: `2000 - 1700` = 300, so `+ 100` gives us 400. Not sure though why `aux` is used to determine the leap year in that lime and not just `year` itself.

Comment: What is `offset` here?

Answer (score 18):

If you have dates as a string, it might be easier to do it using pandas' Timestamp

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.Timestamp("2019-04-12")
print(df.dayofweek, df.weekday_name)
```

Output:

```
4 Friday
```

Answer (score 15):

Here's a simple code snippet to solve this problem

```
import datetime

intDay = datetime.date(year=2000, month=12, day=1).weekday()
days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
print(days[intDay])
```

The output should be:

```
Friday
```

Answer (score 12):

This is a solution if the date is a datetime object.

```
import datetime
def dow(date):
    days=["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]
    dayNumber=date.weekday()
    print days[dayNumber]
```

Answer (score 10):

datetime library sometimes gives errors with strptime() so I switched to dateutil library. Here's an example of how you can use it :

```
from dateutil import parser
parser.parse('January 11, 2010').strftime("%a")
```

The output that you get from this is `'Mon'`. If you want the output as 'Monday', use the following :

```
parser.parse('January 11, 2010').strftime("%A")
```

This worked for me pretty quickly. I was having problems while using the datetime library because I wanted to store the weekday name instead of weekday number and the format from using the datetime library was causing problems. If you're not having problems with this, great! If you are, you cand efinitely go for this as it has a simpler syntax as well. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 10):

Say you have **timeStamp: String variable, YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS**

**step 1**: convert it to dateTime function with blow code...

```
df['timeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timeStamp'])
```

**Step 2** : Now you can extract all the required feature as below which will create new Column for each of the fild- hour,month,day of week,year, date

```
df['Hour'] = df['timeStamp'].apply(lambda time: time.hour)
df['Month'] = df['timeStamp'].apply(lambda time: time.month)
df['Day of Week'] = df['timeStamp'].apply(lambda time: time.dayofweek)
df['Year'] = df['timeStamp'].apply(lambda t: t.year)
df['Date'] = df['timeStamp'].apply(lambda t: t.day)
```

Comment: Will this edit the my elasticsearch data/columns? For me this would enable the use of bucket aggregations on weekdays for example.

Answer (score 8):

This don't need to day of week comments.
I recommend this code~!

```
import datetime


DAY_OF_WEEK = {
    "MONDAY": 0,
    "TUESDAY": 1,
    "WEDNESDAY": 2,
    "THURSDAY": 3,
    "FRIDAY": 4,
    "SATURDAY": 5,
    "SUNDAY": 6
}

def string_to_date(dt, format='%Y%m%d'):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, format)

def date_to_string(date, format='%Y%m%d'):
    return datetime.datetime.strftime(date, format)

def day_of_week(dt):
    return string_to_date(dt).weekday()


dt = '20210101'
if day_of_week(dt) == DAY_OF_WEEK['SUNDAY']:
    None
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are given the day, month, and year, you could do:

```
import datetime
DayL = ['Mon','Tues','Wednes','Thurs','Fri','Satur','Sun']
date = DayL[datetime.date(year,month,day).weekday()] + 'day'
#Set day, month, year to your value
#Now, date is set as an actual day, not a number from 0 to 6.

print(date)
```

Comment: There is no need of using DayL array as you can directly get day name by using `strftime("%A")` instead of `weekday()`

Answer (score 6):

If you have reason to avoid the use of the datetime module, then this function will work.

Note: The change from the Julian to the Gregorian calendar is assumed to have occurred in 1582. If this is not true for your calendar of interest then change the line *if year > 1582:* accordingly.

```
def dow(year,month,day):
    """ day of week, Sunday = 1, Saturday = 7
     http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence """
    m, q = month, day
    if m == 1:
        m = 13
        year -= 1
    elif m == 2:
        m = 14
        year -= 1
    K = year % 100    
    J = year // 100
    f = (q + int(13*(m + 1)/5.0) + K + int(K/4.0))
    fg = f + int(J/4.0) - 2 * J
    fj = f + 5 - J
    if year > 1582:
        h = fg % 7
    else:
        h = fj % 7
    if h == 0:
        h = 7
    return h
```

Comment: 'A' for effort! You might move statements, like those assigning to `fg` and `fj`, inside the conditional to prevent unnecessary computations.

Answer (score 5):

If you're not solely reliant on the `datetime` module, `calendar` might be a better alternative. This, for example, will provide you with the day codes:

```
calendar.weekday(2017,12,22);
```

And this will give you the day itself:

```
days = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]
days[calendar.weekday(2017,12,22)]
```

Or in the style of python, as a one liner:

```
["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"][calendar.weekday(2017,12,22)]
```

Answer (score 4):

To get Sunday as 1 through Saturday as 7, this is the simplest solution to your question:

```
datetime.date.today().toordinal()%7 + 1
```

All of them:

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
sunday = today - datetime.timedelta(today.weekday()+1)

for i in range(7):
    tmp_date = sunday + datetime.timedelta(i)
    print tmp_date.toordinal()%7 + 1, '==', tmp_date.strftime('%A')
```

Output:

```
1 == Sunday
2 == Monday
3 == Tuesday
4 == Wednesday
5 == Thursday
6 == Friday
7 == Saturday
```

Comment: The question asks for Sunday == 1, Monday == 2, and Friday == 6.

Answer (score 4):

```
import datetime
int(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%w'))+1
```

this should give you your real day number - 1 = sunday, 2 = monday, etc...

Comment: Why would you use `+1`? It is common sence that the weeknumbering in python starts at sundat as 0 and monday as 1.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to convert a list of little endian string dates to `datetime`:

```
import datetime, time
ls = ['31/1/2007', '14/2/2017']
for d in ls:    
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%d/%m/%Y")
    print(dt)
    print(dt.strftime("%A"))
```

Answer (score 3):

**We can take help of Pandas:**

```
import pandas as pd
```

As mentioned above in the problem We have:

```
datetime(2017, 10, 20)
```

If execute this line in the jupyter notebook we have an output like this:

```
datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 20, 0, 0)
```

**Using weekday() and weekday_name:**

If you want weekdays in integer number format then use:

```
pd.to_datetime(datetime(2017, 10, 20)).weekday()
```

The output will be:

```
4
```

And if you want it as name of the day like Sunday, Monday, Friday, etc you can use:

```
pd.to_datetime(datetime(2017, 10, 20)).weekday_name
```

The output will be:

`'Friday'`

**If having a dates column in Pandas dataframe then:**

Now suppose if you have a pandas dataframe having a date column like this:
pdExampleDataFrame['Dates'].head(5)

```
0   2010-04-01
1   2010-04-02
2   2010-04-03
3   2010-04-04
4   2010-04-05
Name: Dates, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Now If we want to know the name of the weekday like Monday, Tuesday, ..etc we can use `.weekday_name` as follows:

```
pdExampleDataFrame.head(5)['Dates'].dt.weekday_name
```

the output will be:

```
0    Thursday
1      Friday
2    Saturday
3      Sunday
4      Monday
Name: Dates, dtype: object
```

And if we want the integer number of weekday from this Dates column then we can use:

```
pdExampleDataFrame.head(5)['Dates'].apply(lambda x: x.weekday())
```

The output will look like this:

```
0    3
1    4
2    5
3    6
4    0
Name: Dates, dtype: int64
```

Comment: In Pandas 1.0 and after, weekday_name() has been changed to day_name()

Answer (score 3):

```
import datetime
import calendar

day, month, year = map(int, input().split())
my_date = datetime.date(year, month, day)
print(calendar.day_name[my_date.weekday()])
```

## Output Sample

```
08 05 2015
Friday
```

Comment: but there was Wednesday on 05/08/2015

Comment: Input given is DD MM YYYY format, perhaps you're interpreting it as MMDDYYYY format.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to generate a column with a range of dates (`Date`) and generate a column that goes to the first one and assigns the Week Day (`Week Day`), do the following (I will used the dates ranging from `2008-01-01` to `2020-02-01`):

```
import pandas as pd
dr = pd.date_range(start='2008-01-01', end='2020-02-1')
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Date'] = dr
df['Week Day'] = pd.to_datetime(dr).weekday
```

The output is the following:

[image]

The `Week Day` varies from 0 to 6, where 0 corresponds to Monday and 6 to Sunday.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a fresh way. Sunday is 0.

```py
from datetime import datetime
today = datetime(year=2022, month=6, day=17)
print(today.toordinal()%7)  # 5
yesterday = datetime(year=1, month=1, day=1)
print(today.toordinal()%7)  # 1
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple, straightforward and still not mentioned option:

```
import datetime
...
givenDateObj = datetime.date(2017, 10, 20)
weekday      = givenDateObj.isocalendar()[2] # 5
weeknumber   = givenDateObj.isocalendar()[1] # 42
```

Answer (score 2):

If u are Chinese user, u can use this package:
https://github.com/LKI/chinese-calendar

```
import datetime

# 判断 2018年4月30号 是不是节假日
from chinese_calendar import is_holiday, is_workday
april_last = datetime.date(2018, 4, 30)
assert is_workday(april_last) is False
assert is_holiday(april_last) is True

# 或者在判断的同时，获取节日名
import chinese_calendar as calendar  # 也可以这样 import
on_holiday, holiday_name = calendar.get_holiday_detail(april_last)
assert on_holiday is True
assert holiday_name == calendar.Holiday.labour_day.value

# 还能判断法定节假日是不是调休
import chinese_calendar
assert chinese_calendar.is_in_lieu(datetime.date(2006, 2, 1)) is False
assert chinese_calendar.is_in_lieu(datetime.date(2006, 2, 2)) is True
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Canlendar Module

```
import calendar
a=calendar.weekday(year,month,day)
days=["MONDAY","TUESDAY","WEDNESDAY","THURSDAY","FRIDAY","SATURDAY","SUNDAY"]
print(days[a])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my python3 implementation.

```
months = {'jan' : 1, 'feb' : 4, 'mar' : 4, 'apr':0, 'may':2, 'jun':5, 'jul':6, 'aug':3, 'sep':6, 'oct':1, 'nov':4, 'dec':6}
dates = {'Sunday':1, 'Monday':2, 'Tuesday':3, 'Wednesday':4, 'Thursday':5, 'Friday':6, 'Saterday':0}
ranges = {'1800-1899':2, '1900-1999':0, '2000-2099':6, '2100-2199':4, '2200-2299':2}

def getValue(val, dic):
    if(len(val)==4):
        for k,v in dic.items():
            x,y=int(k.split('-')[0]),int(k.split('-')[1])
            val = int(val)
            if(val>=x and val<=y):
                return v
    else:
        return dic[val]

def getDate(val):
    return (list(dates.keys())[list(dates.values()).index(val)]) 



def main(myDate):
    dateArray = myDate.split('-')
    # print(dateArray)
    date,month,year = dateArray[2],dateArray[1],dateArray[0]
    # print(date,month,year)

    date = int(date)
    month_v = getValue(month, months)
    year_2 = int(year[2:])
    div = year_2//4
    year_v = getValue(year, ranges)
    sumAll = date+month_v+year_2+div+year_v
    val = (sumAll)%7
    str_date = getDate(val)

    print('{} is a {}.'.format(myDate, str_date))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    testDate = '2018-mar-4'
    main(testDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

def date(df):
    df['weekday'] = df['date'].dt.day_name()

    conditions = [(df['weekday'] == 'Sunday'),
              (df['weekday'] == 'Monday'),
              (df['weekday'] == 'Tuesday'),
              (df['weekday'] == 'Wednesday'),
              (df['weekday'] == 'Thursday'),
              (df['weekday'] == 'Friday'),
              (df['weekday'] == 'Saturday')]

    choices = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

    df['week'] = np.select(conditions, choices)

    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to enter date in the format of DD-MM-YYYY you can change the input format by changing the order of '%d-%m-%Y' and also by changing the delimiter.

```
import datetime
try:
    date = input()
    date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d-%m-%Y')
    print(date_time_obj.strftime('%A'))
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid date.")
```

Answer (score -1):

use this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
print(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['give_date']).day)
```

Answer (score -1):

It will print the present week's Monday and Friday, and by adjusting **days** value, we can also print the remaining days of the week

```
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime as dt
today = dt.date.today()
monday = today - timedelta(days=today.weekday())
friday = monday + timedelta(days=4)
```

Answer (score -2):

In MATLAB, Gauss' method

```
day_name={'Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'}
month_offset=[0 3 3 6 1 4 6 2 5 0 3 5];  % common year

% input date
y1=2022
m1=11
d1=22

% is y1 leap
if mod(y1,4)==0 && mod(y1,100)==0 && mod(y1,400)==0
    month_offset=[0 3 4 0 2 5 0 3 6 1 4 6];  % offset for leap year
end

% Gregorian calendar
weekday_gregor=rem( d1+month_offset(m1) + 5*rem(y1-1,4) +  4*rem(y1-1,100) + 6*rem(y1-1,400),7)

day_name{weekday_gregor+1}
```

0: Sunday 1: Monday .. 6: Saturday