# In Python i need a day_name function

Tags: python, python-3.3, dayofweek

A question I can't work out, is how to write a function `day_name` that converts an integer 0-6 into Sunday to Monday, 0 being Sunday.

I found this helpful but the year and month confuse me = [which day of week given a date python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/which-day-of-week-given-a-date-python)

Comment: That question explains how to calculate it from a given *date*. You don't have a date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is a list of weekdays:

```
weekdays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
```

then use the day integer as an index:

```
def day_name(day):
    return weekdays[day]
```

This works because Python lists use 0-based indexing:

```
>>> weekdays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
>>> weekdays[0]
'Sunday'
>>> weekdays[5]
'Friday'
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi here is your function

```
def dayOfTheWeek(n):
    if n == 0:
       return "Sunday"
    elif n == 1:
       return "Monday"
    elif n == 2:
       return "Tuesday"
    elif n == 3:
       return "Wednesday"
    elif n == 4:
       return "Thursday"
    elif n == 5:
       return "Friday"
    elif n == 6:
       return "Saturday"
    else:
       return "Invalid Number"
```

I hope thats what you are looking for :)

Comment: it works but not very pythonic...

Comment: Ya you are right but i think the guy need simple solution so that he can understand.. that why i wrote this..

Comment: fair enough, you get a +1 :-)

Comment: The simpler solution is to use a dictionary; map a key to a string. The simplest solution is to use a list, since the keys here are contiguous positive integers starting at 0.

Comment: Thanks but it says there is a syntax error in first line?

Comment: Hi Marco,
Sorry i miss : after dayOfTheWeek(n) now try the code.. Thanks

Comment: Marco go to the site..
http://repl.it/languages/Python
And run the code..

def dayOfTheWeek(n):
    if n == 0:
       return "Sunday"
    elif n == 1:
       return "Monday"
    elif n == 2:
       return "Tuesday"
    elif n == 3:
       return "Wednesday"
    elif n == 4:
       return "Thursday"
    elif n == 5:
       return "Friday"
    elif n == 6:
       return "Saturday"
    else:
       return "Invalid Number"
       
print dayOfTheWeek(4)