# Incrementing date whilst ignoring weekends

Tags: python, date

I am currently writing a support rota for my workplace.

The code itself is simple

```
import itertools

names = ["P1", "P2", "P3"]

extns = {'P1': 'xxxx', 'P2': 'xxxy', 'P3': 'xxyy'}

for _ in itertools.repeat(None, 5):
    for name in names:
        print name + " | " + extns[name]
```

(*Names replaced with Pn and numbers replaced with "x/y" substitutes*)

This works great so far and gives me the expected output of

```
P1 | xxxx
P2 | xxxy
P3 | xxyy
```

repeated 5 times.

However the desired output is

```
| <Todays Date> | P1 | xxxx |
```

Obviously I could just use a calendar Lib and use the data from there and then just do something such a `today+1` for tomorrow's date etc.

The problem occurs when trying to skip weekend.

Working a 5 day week means we do not allocate support on weekends (Saturday/Sunday 0000-2400)

For example for September the 1st was a monday so I would want the dates to be

```
01-09-14
02-09-14
03-09-14
04-09-14
05-09-14
08-09-14
09-09-14
```

As you can see it skips the 6th and 7th as that is a saturday and sunday.

I have looked at the `calendar` module and found code for:

```
calendar.setfirstday()
```

Which sounds promising, I can also use

```
iterweekdays()
```

to return and iterator for weekdays.

I'm not sure though whether this would give dates if I were to iterate through it. I am also unsure how I would actually iterate through it.

EDIT:

Below is expected output:

```
| 10-09-14 | P1 | xxxx | 
| 11-09-14 | P2 | xxxy | 
| 12-09-14 | P3 | xxyy | 
| 15-09-14 | P1 | xxxx | 
| 16-09-14 | P2 | xxxy | 
| 17-09-14 | P3 | xxyy | 
| 18-09-14 | P1 | xxxx |  
| 19-09-14 | P2 | xxxy | 
| 22-09-14 | P3 | xxxy | 
| 23-09-14 | P1 | xxxx | 
| 24-09-14 | P2 | xxxy | 
| 25-09-14 | P3 | xxyy | 
| 26-09-14 | P1 | xxxx | 
| 29-09-14 | P2 | xxxy | 
| 30-09-14 | P3 | xxyy |
```

Currently I can get todays date and check whether or not it is a weekday. The problem then is going ahead in time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/which-day-of-week-given-a-date-python  maybe this will help?

Comment: Check out https://labix.org/python-dateutil

Comment: Can you elaborate on the expected output? Is the date being printed for every line, for every 3 lines (P1, P2, P3) or for each loop through `itertools.repeat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import itertools
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

names = ["P1", "P2", "P3"]
extns = {'P1': 'xxxx', 'P2': 'xxxy', 'P3': 'xxyy'}

for (day,name) in itertools.izip((day for day in (datetime.today()+timedelta(n) for n in itertools.count()) if day.weekday() not in (5,6)), (itertools.cycle(names))):
    print "| %s | %s | %s |" % (day.strftime("%d-%m-%y"), name, extns[name])
```

Starts the count from today and loops indefinitely. I only assume that's what you desired as that's how your original code as structured. If you want it for specific time frames only let me know.

---

EDIT: As per comments, this should print out only today + 10 days. This could probably be done numerous ways but this way you can easily edit how many days you want even down to just today:

```
import itertools
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

names = ["P1", "P2", "P3"]
extns = {'P1': 'xxxx', 'P2': 'xxxy', 'P3': 'xxyy'}
days = 11

for (day,name) in itertools.izip((day for day in (datetime.today()+timedelta(n) for n in itertools.count()) if day.weekday() not in (5,6)), (itertools.cycle(names))):    
    if days == 0:
        break

    print "| %s | %s | %s |" % (day.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"), name, extns[name])
    days-= 1
```

Comment: This looks fantastic. In regards to timeframes, I am looking for it to do 10 lines. Eg. Today and then 10 working days ahead. I think this would be the same as it iterating 10 times.

Comment: @JoeSmart the supplied edit should print out today + 10 days for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `datetime` and its `.weekday()` function which maps the days of a week to 0-6 beginning with monday = 0 and ending with sunday = 6.

```
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.today()  # get todays datetime

if not today.weekday() == 5 or today.weekday == 6:   # if we no weekend-day

    print(datetime.strftime(today,'%d-%m-%y')) # format it to day-month-year
```

Comment: This works great. How would I be able to add to `datetime.today()` in order to the tomorrow, the day after that etc. The rota needs to forecast 2 weeks ahead. EG. today + 14

Comment: `datetime` has a `timedelta` object which you could use to add days.
For example `x = datetime.timedelta(days=14)`  and then  `future = today + x` and you get a new `datetime` object

Comment: It also has to give the dates for all days inbetween, sorry if I wasn't clear. I've added expected output to my original question to make it a bit clearer

Answer (score 2):

you could use [weekday](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.weekday) of calendar, if that returns 5 or 6, you can consider as weekend.

EDIT:
You could do following with datetime:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d=datetime.date(2014,9,10)
>>> d.weekday()
2
```

Comment: I see that the `weekday` function takes 3 arguments `(year, month, day)` is it possible to have them automatically filled, the whole idea is that it's automated. eg. setting them to some variable

Comment: Please see my edit..d is already there in your code, so you donot need second line in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

This might give you some ideas.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

'''
A generator that returns the dates of consecutive days, skipping weekends
'''

import sys
import datetime

def weekday_gen(current_date):
    day_delta = datetime.timedelta(1)
    while True:
        if current_date.weekday() < 5: 
            yield current_date
        current_date += day_delta


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) > 3:
        d, m, y = [int(s) for s in sys.argv[1:4]]
        start_date = datetime.date(y, m, d)
    else:
        start_date = datetime.date.today()

    weekdays = weekday_gen(start_date)
    for i in xrange(30):
        day = weekdays.next()
        print day, day.strftime('%A')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But what do you do about public holidays...