# How to get weekday name in locale format from number in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How to get weekday name in locale format from number in Python?

It it other method to get weekday name in Python that setting date to monday and using `strftime('%a')` than adding `timedelta(day=1)`.

Comment: do  you mean [`calendar.day_abbr[0]`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/calendar.html#calendar.day_abbr) ?

Comment: ... or  `calendar.MONDAY` ?

Answer (score 3):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29519293/1418255):

You can use

```
>>> import calendar
>>> dayoftheweek = 2
>>> calendar.day_name[dayoftheweek]
'Wednesday'
```

Where `Monday = 0, Tuesday = 1` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the weekday names like this:

```
import locale

locale.nl_langinfo(locale.DAY_1)
locale.nl_langinfo(locale.DAY_2)
locale.nl_langinfo(locale.DAY_3)
locale.nl_langinfo(locale.DAY_4)
locale.nl_langinfo(locale.DAY_5)
locale.nl_langinfo(locale.DAY_6)
locale.nl_langinfo(locale.DAY_7)
```

Still a bit unsatisfactory that you cannot specify the weekday as an integer variable. In my environment you can do it like this, as it happens:

```
locale.nl_langinfo(locale.DAY_1 + x)
```

but the docs don't guarantee it.