# django date field get day of a week like sunday monday

Tags: python, django

I have a `DateField` in django whose default value is set to `timezone.now`

How can I get the week of the day. I mean the day is either sunday or monday or other ??

Comment: See: [which day of week given a date python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/which-day-of-week-given-a-date-python)

Comment: In `views.py` or in a template?

Comment: @Chris in views and template both

Answer (score 9):

A Django [`DateField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#datefield) is

> represented in Python by a `datetime.date` instance

So in Python code you can use [`date.weekday()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime.date#datetime.date.weekday) or [`date.isoweekday()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime.date#datetime.date.weekday) on it.

In a template you should use the [`date` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#date), e.g.

```
Today is {{ date_variable|date:"l" }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a small piece of code to do that:

```
import datetime
from django.db import models

def get_monday():
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    return today - datetime.timedelta(today.weekday())

class MyModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=get_monday)
```

also sunday:

```
def get_sunday():
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    return today + datetime.timedelta(7 - today.weekday() - 1)
```