# how to get weekday from a given date in python?

Tags: python, datetime

**2001-10-18**
 I want to calculate weekday e.g. Monday, Tuesday from the date given above. is it possible in python?

Comment: yes it's possible, did you try something ?

Comment: did you try searching for already existing questions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/which-day-of-week-given-a-date-python check this one out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [which day of week given a date python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/which-day-of-week-given-a-date-python)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is one way to do this:

```
dt = '2001-10-18'
year, month, day = (int(x) for x in dt.split('-'))    
answer = datetime.date(year, month, day).weekday()
```

Comment: You can just use `format` to convert ISO datetime.

Answer (score 6):

There is the `weekday()` and `isoweekday()` methods for datetime objects.

[Python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have that got me if a leap year and also days in a given month (accounts for leap years). Finding out a specific day of the week, that I'm also stuck on.

```
def is_year_leap(year):
    if (year & 4) == 0:
        return True
    if (year % 100) == 0:
        return False
    if (year % 400) == 0:
        return True
    return False

def days_in_month(year, month):
    if month == 1 or month == 3 or month == 5 or month == 7 or month == 8 or month == 10 or month == 12:
        return 31
    if month == 2:
        if is_year_leap(year):
            return 29
        else:
            return 28
    if month == 4 or month == 6 or month == 9 or month == 11:
        return 31
```