# Pandas convert quarterly to daily while keeping distinct tickers in mind

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing, reindex

I'm working on pulling financial data, in which some is formatted in quarterly and other is daily. My model will need all of it daily, therefore I need that same quarterly value repeated for each day. I've been using this [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612705/converting-pandas-dataframe-from-monthly-to-daily) and trying to adapt the code to my data.

Here is my dataframe head:

```
  date        ticker   value
0 31/03/1980  ECB/RA6  1.0
1 30/06/1980  ECB/RA6  4.0
2 30/09/1980  ECB/RA6  2.0
3 30/12/1980  ECB/RA6  3.0
4 31/03/1981  ECB/RA6  2.0
```

Here is my desired output looks like:

```
   date        ticker   value
0  01/01/1980  ECB/RA6  1.0
1  02/01/1980  ECB/RA6  1.0
2  03/01/1980  ECB/RA6  1.0
3  04/01/1980  ECB/RA6  1.0
4  05/01/1980  ECB/RA6  1.0
.  .           .        .
.  .           .        .
.  .           .        .
91 01/04/1980  ECB/RA6  4.0
```

And my code:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
df = df.pivot(index='date', columns='ticker')
start_date = df.index.min() - pd.DateOffset(day=1)
end_date = df.index.max() + pd.DateOffset(day=31)
dates = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='d')
dates.name = 'date'
df = df.reindex(dates, method='ffill')

df = df.stack('ticker')
df = df.sortlevel(level=1)
df = df.reset_index()
```

**I see now what the problem is, but it shoudn't be a problem i believe.** I run the following code from @Pierre D(after removing duplicates):

```
df = df.set_index('date')  # assuming 'date' is a proper Timestamp
df.index = df.index.to_period('Q')  # turn index into PeriodIndex('Q')
df = df.set_index('ticker', append=True).squeeze()
df2 = df[df.duplicated( keep = False)]
```

I get the following output for df2:

```
                value   value2
date    ticker      
1997Q2  AAPL    46850   NaN
1997Q3  AAPL    46850   NaN
2003Q1  MSFT    10137   19/12/2003
2003Q2  MSFT    10137   19/12/2003
```

As you can see the index is different, but value and value2 are equal in these instances. This should not be a problem I believe, but when I now run:

```
df.unstack()
```

I get the following error: "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: You must have multiple tickers in the same dataframe?

Comment: Can you create a separate column for each ticker? That way you can index by date.

Comment: @JakobL Yes there are more than 600 tickers in my ticker column. Furthermore, to make the question better to read, I have left out other columns. So, besides the "value" column there are other columns. I'm unsure if it would be wise/feasible to approach it from that perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

The question was modified to indicate that there were other columns beside `'value'`, and from some of the comments I gather that "going wide" might be a concern (note: we routinely handle similar timeseries with thousands of columns without any problem).

So, here is another take. It does the same initial step of transforming the purported `'date'` into what it really is: a quarterly `Period`. But then it applies a way of resampling `time` in a multi-index `(time, key)` by groups of `key`. There are several StackOverflow answers to that question, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45651543/758174).

All together (with an example):

```
# setup for example
txt = """  date        ticker   value   value2
0 31/03/1980  ECB/RA6  1.0  NA
1 30/06/1980  another  4.0  NA
2 30/09/1980  ECB/RA6  2.0  19/12/2003
3 30/12/1980  ECB/RA6  3.0  19/12/2003
4 31/03/1981  ECB/RA6  2.0  19/12/2003
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(re.sub(r' +', '\t', txt)),
                 sep='\t', index_col=[0],
                 parse_dates=['date', 'value2'])

# set date as index and convert to quarterly periods
df = df.set_index('date')
df.index = df.index.to_period('Q')

# and now the new resample method (here monthly,
# but change to 'D' for daily)
df = df.groupby('ticker').resample('M').ffill()
```

You can then `.reset_index()` if you prefer, or just leave it as is. Here is the result without resetting the index:

```
>>> df
                  ticker  value     value2
ticker  date                              
ECB/RA6 1980-03  ECB/RA6    1.0        NaT
        1980-04  ECB/RA6    1.0        NaT
        1980-05  ECB/RA6    1.0        NaT
        1980-06  ECB/RA6    1.0        NaT
        1980-07  ECB/RA6    1.0        NaT
        1980-08  ECB/RA6    1.0        NaT
        1980-09  ECB/RA6    2.0 2003-12-19
        1980-10  ECB/RA6    2.0 2003-12-19
        1980-11  ECB/RA6    2.0 2003-12-19
        1980-12  ECB/RA6    3.0 2003-12-19
        1981-01  ECB/RA6    3.0 2003-12-19
        1981-02  ECB/RA6    3.0 2003-12-19
        1981-03  ECB/RA6    2.0 2003-12-19
another 1980-06  another    4.0        NaT
```

---

**Original answer**

Here is what I would do: first, set your `date` to be the index and convert it into a `PeriodIndex`, then make your `df` "wide" by putting each ticker into a column. Then just resample:

```
df = df.set_index('date')  # assuming 'date' is a proper Timestamp
df.index = df.index.to_period('Q')  # turn index into PeriodIndex('Q')
df = df.set_index('ticker', append=True).squeeze().unstack()  # make wide: 1 col per ticker
df.resample('D').ffill()  # resample to daily, repeating the values
```

Outcome:

```
             value
ticker     ECB/RA6
date              
1980-01-01     1.0
1980-01-02     1.0
1980-01-03     1.0
1980-01-04     1.0
1980-01-05     1.0
...            ...
1981-03-27     2.0
1981-03-28     2.0
1981-03-29     2.0
1981-03-30     2.0
1981-03-31     2.0
```

Perhaps it's easier to inspect the outcome if you resample by month instead:

```
df.resample('M').ffill()  # resample to daily, repeating the values

# out:
ticker   ECB/RA6
date            
1980-01      1.0
1980-02      1.0
1980-03      1.0
1980-04      4.0
1980-05      4.0
1980-06      4.0
1980-07      2.0
1980-08      2.0
1980-09      2.0
1980-10      3.0
1980-11      3.0
1980-12      3.0
1981-01      2.0
1981-02      2.0
1981-03      2.0
```

Incidentally, it is useful to observe what happens with missing data:

```
# with input df as:
        date   ticker  value
0 1980-03-31  ECB/RA6    1.0
1 1980-06-30  another    4.0
2 1980-09-30  ECB/RA6    2.0

# output:
ticker   ECB/RA6  another
date                     
1980-01      1.0      NaN
1980-02      1.0      NaN
1980-03      1.0      NaN
1980-04      NaN      4.0
1980-05      NaN      4.0
1980-06      NaN      4.0
1980-07      2.0      NaN
1980-08      2.0      NaN
1980-09      2.0      NaN
```

Final note: of course, you can stack again the result if you want to get it as a tall and skinny table (and even reset the index, if you prefer):

```
print(df.resample('M').ffill().stack().reset_index())

# out:
      date   ticker    0
0  1980-01  ECB/RA6  1.0
1  1980-02  ECB/RA6  1.0
2  1980-03  ECB/RA6  1.0
3  1980-04  another  4.0
4  1980-05  another  4.0
5  1980-06  another  4.0
6  1980-07  ECB/RA6  2.0
7  1980-08  ECB/RA6  2.0
8  1980-09  ECB/RA6  2.0
```

Comment: When I run your code I get the exact same error message as when I run my own code: "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape". This error occurs in the third line of your code: df = df.set_index('ticker', append=True).squeeze().unstack(). I believe that this is caused by the fact that there are duplicates in the date column.

Comment: Do you mean that `df.groupby(['date', 'ticker']).size().max() > 1'`? Repeating dates (for different tickers) would be expected and handled just fine, but not repeated values of the `(date, ticker)` tuple. If there are, you need to decide how to handle the values (if different). One quick first check is `df.drop_duplicates()` in case some entire rows are repeated.

Comment: You were right that there were duplicates in the data for the `(date,ticker)` tuple. However, when I use `df = df.drop_duplicates(['date','ticker'])` and get `df.groupby(['date', 'ticker']).size().max() = 1` I still get the same error at the `unstack()` part of the code.

Comment: I edited the question and specified what specifically appears to cause this error. It appears to be a problem where not the date and ticker (the index tuple) are duplicates, but the remaining values of the dataframe. I fail to understand why those values are required to be different by `unstack()` though.

Comment: ok, since having multiple columns changes the question, I adapted the answer. Please see if that works for you.