# Filtering csv file based on user input with python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, input

I have a large data base that looks like this:

```
id, Start Time, End Time
0, 2017-01-01 00:00:21, 2017-01-01 00:11:41
1, 2017-01-01 00:00:45, 2017-01-01 00:11:46
2, 2017-02-01 00:00:57, 2017-02-01 00:22:08
3, 2017-03-01 00:01:10, 2017-03-01 00:11:42
4, 2017-01-01 00:01:51, 2017-01-01 00:12:57
```

Using pandas would probably be easier to do this, but I don't have much experience with it. I have researched modules such as `arrow` and `datetime` and would like to filter the data based on the user's input. Using that input, the user is returned filtered data. For example:

```
def get_month('data.csv'):
    month = input('\nWhich month? January, February, March, April, May, or June?\n')
    date = '1 ' + month + ', 2017'
    with open(city_data, 'r') as fin, open('userdata.csv', 'w') as fout:
         writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=' ')
         for row in csv.reader(fin, delimiter=' '):
             if row[0] == arrow.get(date,'D MMMM, YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD'):
                 return writer.writerow(row)
```

Am I approaching this correctly? I think I may be going in the wrong direction in the `date = '1 ' + month + ', 2017'` part. Is there a way I could filter the data with just an input like `January`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For structured data, `pandas` provides an efficient solution:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

# read data from file
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# this creates a dataframe as below:
#    id           Start Time             End Time
# 0   0  2017-01-01 00:00:21  2017-01-01 00:11:41
# 1   1  2017-01-01 00:00:45  2017-01-01 00:11:46
# 2   2  2017-02-01 00:00:57  2017-02-01 00:22:08
# 3   3  2017-03-01 00:01:10  2017-03-01 00:11:42
# 4   4  2017-01-01 00:01:51  2017-01-01 00:12:57

# cast string columns to datetime
df['Start Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time'])
df['End Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End Time'])

def get_month(df):
    month = input('\nWhich month? January, February, March, April, May, or June?\n')
    return df[df['Start Time'].dt.month == datetime.strptime(month, '%B').month]

get_month(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Looks like I'm going with pandas. It looks so elegant and easy to understand. I was able to look up a few things in the docs based on your answer and I pretty much understand it now. Thanks again!

Comment: if I wanted to do the same thing above but filter by day would the code look like this? `return city_data[city_data['Start Time'].dt.day == datetime.strptime(day, '%A').day]` @jp

Comment: If the input is an integer, you could just do `return city_data[city_data['Start Time'].dt.day == day_input`,  where `day_input` is the integer input by the user. But remember to use `day_input = int(input('What day?'))`, as by default inputs are strings [so convert to int].

Comment: Awesome, that worked. Thank you. Out of curiosity, would the method above work for a response like `Monday` ?

Comment: The answer to your question is already "out there", see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29519293/9209546). In general, I'm happy to help, but please try and do a simple search first.. it makes sure we respond when you really get stuck!