# Get the day of week given a date

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on my project on a timetable app. I can get the date with:

```
import datetime  
now = datetime.datetime.now()  
print (now.day, "/", now.month, "/", now.year)
```

But I can't get the day of the week though. Can someone help me?

Comment: use `weekday()`

Answer (score 2):

To format and print dates, you should use the `strftime` functions (see the [strftime python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)) instead of manually build your own format.

so e.g.

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now.strftime("%A, %d/%m/%Y"))
```

Check out the doc, for the full list of styles. Maybe you want `%a` (abbreviated weekday name, or also `%b` or `%B` for the month name.

If you need just the values, check the `datetime` documenation, in the same page: you have `now.weekday()` (Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6), or `now.iweekday()` (Monday is 1 and Sunday is 7).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your comments really helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import time

localtime = time.localtime(time.time())
current_time = time.asctime(localtime)
```

print(current_time[:3])

This should work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent answer by @seddonym on https://stackoverflow.com/a/29519293/4672536 to find the day of the week. I will post the code here for reference. Good luck! :) :

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> import calendar
>>> my_date = date.today()
>>> calendar.day_name[my_date.weekday()]
'Wednesday'
```