# python - find year given day, month, and weekday name

Tags: python, datetime

I have a column of strings that give me month and day and day name as

```
Date      Week Day
03-03     Friday
03-19     Saturday
03-18     Saturday
03-18     Monday
....
```

I want to return the most recent year, given those months and days, but also given the name of day.

so

```
Date     Week Day       Max Year
03-03    Friday         2018
03-19    Saturday       2016
03-18    Saturday       2017
03-18    Monday         2013
....
```

EDIT: Sorry forgot to add what I was thinking and trying

So I'm trying to do something like:

```
from datetime import datetime
day = 28
month = 3
name = 'Monday'
t = datetime.strptime('{}_{}_{}'.format(month,day,name), '%d_%m_%A')
t.strftime('%Y')
```

But it stores year as 1900. I'm just not sure how to get it to return the year as the most recent, or maxyear?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Have a look at this question. It will help you get started - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/how-do-i-get-the-day-of-week-given-a-date-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you will have to write a for loop to search for the most recent year. This shows an example of how you can do that.

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today() # This would be the user input date
weekday = 1 # look for the most recent Tuesday on today's date
while(today.weekday() != weekday and today.year > 1000):
    today = today.replace(year=today.year - 1) # subtract one year from the date
    if today.weekday() == weekday:
        print("The Most recent Tuesday was in:",today.year)
        break

if today.year <= 1000:
    print("No Date found matching critieria since year 1000 AD")
```

Comment: It works up until I try to do february 29. Because the input needs to include the year, if you do a year that's not a leap year, it'll return a ValueError.

Comment: Interesting, it looks like you will have to detect if it is a leap year somehow