# How can I create a program that determines the first day of any 4 digit year by python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given a 4 digit year, return the number of the day on which January 1st falls. 0 is Sunday, …, 6 is Saturday

Comment: This is probably too broad for SO.  I would start writing some code and come back if you have a specific issue.

Comment: However, you probably want: `datetime.datetime(1967, 1, 1).weekday()` Although Sunday is 6 in that format, and Monday is 0.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/how-do-i-get-the-day-of-week-given-a-date-in-python Might be a dupe.

Comment: @Tshilidzi what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `datetime` library

```
import datetime

d = datetime.date(year, 1, 1)
weekday = d.isoweekday() % 7
```

The `datetime` library starts all weeks on Monday, so you need to do a bit of a conversion to get `Sunday` to be `0`

Comment: @chrisz Yes, for `weekday()`, it's Mon-Sun (0-6), `isoweekday()` is still Mon-Sun, but it runs `1-7`, I'm just converting `7` to `0`