# Finding the dates of monday through sunday given the week day, and current date

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on a discord bot for one of my servers, and for this piece of it to work, I need it to bring up the dates for Monday through Sunday when given the current date, and week day. I would like to avoid using a lot of if statements if possible.

**What I have tried:** I have tried using if statements to complete this task, but just find it makes too much work, and messy code.

**Parts of current code:**

*The Date*

```
time = ctx.message.timestamp
day = time.day
month = time.month
year = time.year
date = [year, month, day]
```

*The Week Day:*

```
with open(dir_data + "Week Day.txt",'r+') as f:
    system_day = f.readline()
```

**Note:** The week day is in the form of a number. (Ex. Monday = 1)

Comment: You can find the weekday like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9847269/4737952

Comment: Oh, I did not know that. Thank you for the information, I will use it to improve my code in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the module `weekday()` to know the day of the week:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.today().weekday()
```

`date.weekday()` returns the day of the week as an integer, where Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6. For example, `date(2002, 12, 4).weekday()` is 2, which means it is a Wednesday.

In your case, you want to generate the days from Monday to Sunday, so the following function which returns a dictionary where its keys are the week days, and its values the dates corresponding to that day might be useful:

```
import datetime

def generate_week_days(date):
    weekday = date.weekday()
    offset = [i - weekday for i in range(7)]
    days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
    dates = [(date + datetime.timedelta(days)).date() for days in offset] 

    return {days[date.weekday()]: date for date in dates}
```

Example:

```
d = datetime.datetime.now()
print(generate_week_days(d))
```

This will print:

```
{'Monday': datetime.date(2018, 7, 9),
 'Tuesday': datetime.date(2018, 7, 10),
 'Wednesday': datetime.date(2018, 7, 11),
 'Thursday': datetime.date(2018, 7, 12),
 'Friday': datetime.date(2018, 7, 13),
 'Saturday': datetime.date(2018, 7, 14),
 'Sunday': datetime.date(2018, 7, 15)}
```

Comment: But I wanted the dates of Monday through sunday, not the current day

Comment: Is ther a way to return them as Monday =, Tuesday =, etc?

Comment: @John.B, what do you mean? as a dictionary?

Comment: I want it to generate the dates of Monday through sunday

Comment: @John.B, I have updated my answer once again? Is that what you are looking for? if not, would you mind providing an input output example please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174982/discussion-between-lmiguelvargasf-and-john-b).