# Save Weekday into variable as string and if equal print 'something' python

Tags: python, performance

```
import time
import datetime

date = time.strftime("%A")
week = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"];
weekend = ["Saturday", "Sunday"];

if weekend == date:
    print ("Today is: " + date)
```

/*I want to make schedule.
So when a day is equal 
with one of my days saved in variable
it will print out my schedule for that date. 
As you can see I dont have the schedules yet.
I just need ot know how to save current day as string*/

Comment: Have a look at the following SO answer. This will give you the date https://stackoverflow.com/a/29519293/8411228

Comment: I guess you have the `date` variable correct, i.e., name of day as string. But the `if` check is faulty, it's comparing a list with a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the day of week given a date in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/how-do-i-get-the-day-of-week-given-a-date-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to check if `date` is `in` either of the two collections, `week` or `weekend`. Like:

```
if date in week:  # or weekend
    print('Weekday')
```

Use `set`s for more efficient checking, like:

```
weekend = set(["Saturday", "Sunday"])
```

Also, no semicolons to end a statement.