# Python 3.6 Weekday

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have a combination date/time string 20180104 06:09:36.234 from which I want to find the weekday in python, expecting to get the result for for the date (which is 04 January 2018) as  "4" (ie Thursday) . Have searched far and wide to no avail.Can anyone help please?
Thanks CJ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the day of week given a date in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/how-do-i-get-the-day-of-week-given-a-date-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

[See explanation](https://www.journaldev.com/23365/python-string-to-datetime-strptime) of `datetime.strptime`

```
from datetime import datetime 

date_string = '20180104 06:09:36.234'
date = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
print(date.isoweekday())  # 4
```

Comment: doesn't that give 4 because it's the fourth day in January instead of the fourth day in the week? Better us [`date.isoweekday()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoweekday)

Comment: if he wants 4 for Thursday (and 7 for Sunday), you better use `isoweekday` instead of ´weekday´

Answer (score 0):

Finally worked it out by various combinations of functions:
Identify year, month, date,
Convert to integer,
Use datetime module.

```
import datetime
DateTime = '20180104 06:09:36.234'
Weekday =  datetime.date(int(DateTime[0:4]), int(DateTime[5:6]), 
int(DateTime[7:8])).weekday()
print("Weekday = " ,  Weekday)
```

Weekday = 3

Is there a better way??