# Check the day of the week in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to write code for checking whether it is Sunday or Saturday. But I am getting following error:

The code is:

```
import datetime
def isholiday(date):

    dat0 = date(2019, 3, 23)  # Saturday
    dat1 = date(2019, 3, 24)  # Sunday
    if abs(date - dat0) % 7 == 0 | abs(date - dat1)%7 == 0 :
        print ("is holiday")
    return True
```

In the next line I have:

```
assert(isholiday(datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 21))==True)
```

The error is:

```
     ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
        ---
        TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
        last)
        <ipython-input-22-87d6e5a340a0> in <module>()
        ----> 1 assert(isholiday(datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 21))==True)

        <ipython-input-21-bb556bebaa01> in isholiday(date)
              2 from datetime import date
              3 def isholiday(date):
        ----> 4     dat0 = date(2019,3,23)
              5     dat1 = date(2019,3,24)
              6     if abs(date - dat0)%7 == 0 | abs(date - dat1)%7 == 0 :

        TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `date` of your `isholiday` function shadows the `datetime.date` class. You should rename the parameter to avoid such a naming conflict:

```
def isholiday(dat):
    dat0 = date(2019,3,23) #Saturday
    dat1 = date(2019,3,24)  #Sunday
    if abs(dat - dat0)%7 == 0 | abs(dat - dat1)%7 == 0 :
        print ("is holiday")
        return True
```

Comment: Still getting `NameError: name 'date' is not defined` with this.

Comment: Still getting this _TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'datetime.timedelta' and 'int'_

Comment: You've likely overridden `date` as a global variable elsewhere in your module. Make sure to rename all your variables named `date` in the module to something else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this:

```
dat0 = datetime.datetime(2019,3,23) #Saturday

dat1 = datetime.datetime(2019,3,24)  #Sunday
```

Currently, you are using the 'date' argument in the function and then "calling" it with parentheses and arguments. This is only used when initialising it.

Comment: @MatthewSalvatoreViglione Apologies - a typo. Fixed now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use `weekday()`. Also, your function should always return something, not only sometimes return `True`.

```
from datetime import date

def isholiday(dat):
    if dat.weekday() == 6 or dat.weekday == 5: # 6 is Sunday, 5 is Saturday 
        print ("is holiday")
        return True
    return False

assert(isholiday(date(2018, 10, 21))==True)
```

Gives:

> is holiday

Possible duplicate of: [How do I get the day of week given a date in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/how-do-i-get-the-day-of-week-given-a-date-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code like this:

```
import datetime
def isholiday(date):

    dat0 = datetime.datetime(2019,3,23) #Saturday
    dat1 = datetime.datetime(2019,3,24)  #Sunday
    if abs((date - dat0).days)%7 == 0 or abs((date - dat1).days)%7 == 0:
        print ("is holiday")
        return True

assert(isholiday(datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 21))==True)
```

You are trying to call the 'date' argument and you can't call a datetime.dateime object like this. I changed dates in 5th and 6th line with datetime.datetime. Also you can't use abs() function with datetime.timedelta objects like you use with integers so you should get only the 'day'. I added .days for it.

Comment: Your answer should include an explanation of your code.  See [answer] for more information.