# Python3: Convert arbitrary date to day of the week

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert dates of the following format:

```
2007-10-18 11:31:46 -0400 (Thu, 18 Oct 2007)
```

or

```
Thu, 18 Oct 2007 11:31:49 -0400
```

to the day of the week. Even though the day is given in the above dates, but how can I extract the only day of the week from the above dates?

Comment: Can you add a [mcve]?

Comment: Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/how-do-i-get-the-day-of-week-given-a-date-in-python)

Comment: You can just make a `list` or `dict` with the 7 days of the week and check if one of them is present as text. Or is the day of the week not always present as text?

Answer (score 0):

Is this too simple:

```
days = {
    'mon': 'Monday',
    'thu': 'Thursday',
    # and the others
}

haystack = '2007-10-18 11:31:46 -0400 (Thu, 18 Oct 2007)'
for acronym, full_name in days.items():
    if acronym in haystack.lower():
        print(f"Found {full_name}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
days = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
date = "2007-10-18 11:31:46 -0400 (Thu, 18 Oct 2007)"
for d in days:
    if d in date:
         print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`dateutil.parser`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) to get a `datetime` object from a string:

```
from dateutil import parser
dt = parser.parse("2007-10-18 11:31:46 -0400")
# dt = datetime.datetime(2007, 10, 18, 11, 31, 46, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))
```

Then just use [`datetime.weekday`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.weekday). This will give you a number from `0` to `6`, where `0` is the first day of the week relatively to your timezone, Monday by default.

```
dt.weekday
# 3, starting from 0 so it's Thursday
```