# How to get which day of week is a specific date?

Tags: python

I need to get some information about some dates and I don't know what to use. for example: I pass year, month, day (something like 1990, 5, 15) arguments to a module, and the module returns what day of week is the date we passed. I want it in Python 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the day of week given a date in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/how-do-i-get-the-day-of-week-given-a-date-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a `datetime.date` object you can use the `weekday()` function. Converting to a date object inside your module should be trivial if you are passing in the day, month and year.

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday

**Numeric representation**

Example function:

```
import datetime

def weekday_from_date(day, month, year):
    return datetime.date(day=day, month=month, year=year).weekday()
```

Example usage:

```
>>> weekday_from_date(day=1, month=1, year=1995)
6
```

**String representation**

Combined with the `calendar` module and the `day_name` array you can also get it displayed as a string easily.

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/calendar.html#calendar.day_name

Example function:

```
import datetime
import calendar

def weekday_from_date(day, month, year):
    return calendar.day_name[
        datetime.date(day=day, month=month, year=year).weekday()
    ]
```

Example usage:

```
>>> weekday_from_date(day=1, month=1, year=1995)
'Sunday'
```

**Unit Tests**

Using `pytest` writing a series of super fast unit tests should be straightforward to prove it's correctness. You can add to this suite as you please.

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    ['day', 'month', 'year', 'expected_weekday'],
    [
       (1, 1, 1995, 6),
       (2, 1, 1995, 0),
       (3, 1, 1995, 1),
       (6, 6, 1999, 6)
    ]
)
def test_weekday_from_date(day, month, year, expected_weekday):
    assert weekday_from_date(day, month, year) == expected_weekday
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use weekday() docs. You just have to import datetime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`weekday()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday)

```
import datetime

week = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']

week[datetime.datetime(1990,5,15).weekday()]
```

and you get:

```
'Tuesday'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use datetime module

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = '1990, 5, 15'

date = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y, %m, %d")
date.weekday()

1
```