# Issue with datetime module

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to make a simple Python function that prints
two things;

1. What day of the week it currently is.
2. How many days it is until Christmas.

I don't get any errors when I run this, however nothing prints either. 
In fact nothing at all happens when its run.

I've checked and I've installed the datetime module correctly (I think).

[image: Screenshot of cmd prompt confirmation]

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong so any guidance would be helpful.

As you can probably guess, I'm relatively new to Python/stackoverflow.

Thanks.

**Edit: I stupidly named the file itself datetime.py because yes I am that stupid.**

```
from datetime import *

def day_of_week():
    """ Python function to return a specified day of the week"""
    today_date = date.today()

    thisYear = today_date.year
    xmas = date(thisYear,12,25)

    day_of_week =("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun")[today.weekday]
    print("It's a %s." % (day_of_week))

    days_to_xmas = (xmas - today_date).days
    print("There are %i days to xmas!" & days_to_xmas)
```

Comment: Try .today().weekday() this answer may help your problem:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/how-do-i-get-the-day-of-week-given-a-date][1]

Comment: You define the function to later call it, or use it. Simply add `day_of_week()` in the last line and run the full script again, It should print something or generate an error if there's something wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks for all your contributions.                                                                                                                               My issue was that I stupidly named, the python script "datetime.py"

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the function in the script , you defined the function but never executed it.

day_of_week()

Comment: Thanks for your help, I mistakenly named the file datetime.py which was my issue.