# how can I align different-day timeseries in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have two time series, `df1`

```
       day        cnt
2020-03-01  135006282
2020-03-02  145184482
2020-03-03  146361872
2020-03-04  147702306
2020-03-05  148242336
```

and `df2`:

```
       day        cnt
2017-03-01  149104078
2017-03-02  149781629
2017-03-03  151963252
2017-03-04  147384922
2017-03-05  143466746
```

The problem is that the sensors I'm measuring are sensitive to the day of the week, so on Sunday, for instance, they will produce less `cnt`. Now I need to compare the time series over 2 different years, 2017 and 2020, but to do that I have to align (March, in this case) to the matching day of the week, and plot them accordingly. How do I "shift" the data to make the series comparable?

Comment: Can you include some sample output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ISO calendar is a representation of date in a tuple (year, weeknumber, weekday). In pandas they are the `dt` members `year`, `weekofyear` and `weekday`. So assuming that the `day` column actually contains `Timestamps` (convert if first with `to_datetime` if it does not), you could do:

```
df1['Y'] = df1.day.dt.year
df1['W'] = df1.day.dt.weekofyear
df1['D'] = df1.day.dt.weekday
```

Then you could align the dataframes on the `W` and `D` columns

Comment: Thanks! "Align" how, though?

Comment: `df1.merge(df2,on=['W','D'], how='inner')` If you combine them in this way, you get a single line.

Comment: `.weekday` is now `.weekday()` on newer datetime versions.

Answer (score 0):

March 2017 started on wednesday
March 2020 started on Sunday
So, delete the last 3 days of march 2017
So, delete the first sunday, monday and tuesday from 2020
this way you have comparable days

```
df1['ctn2020'] = df1['cnt']
df2['cnt2017'] = df2['cnt'] 
df1 = df1.iloc[2:, 2]
df2 = df2.iloc[:-3, 2]
```

Since you don't want to plot the date, but want the months to align, make a new dataframe with both columns and a index column. This way you will have 3 columns: index(0-27), 2017 and 2020. The index will represent.

```
new_df = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
```

If you also want to plot the days of the week on the x axis, check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/how-do-i-get-the-day-of-week-given-a-date), to know how to get the day of the week from a date, and them change the x ticks label.

Sorry for the "written step-to-stop", if it all sounds confusing, i can type the whole code later for you.