# Calendar.weekday ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, datetime, calendar

I have a DataFrame with dates as an index:

`DatetimeIndex(['2020-04-01', '2020-04-02', '2020-04-03', '2020-04-06', '2020-04-07', '2020-04-08', '2020-04-09', '2020-04-10', '2020-04-14', '2020-04-15', '2020-04-16', '2020-04-17', '2020-04-20', '2020-04-21', '2020-04-22', '2020-04-23', '2020-04-24', '2020-04-27', '2020-04-28', '2020-04-29', '2020-04-30', '2020-05-04', '2020-05-05', '2020-05-06', '2020-05-07', '2020-05-08', '2020-05-11', '2020-05-12', '2020-05-13', '2020-05-14', '2020-05-15', '2020-05-18', '2020-05-19', '2020-05-20', '2020-05-21', '2020-05-22', '2020-05-25', '2020-05-26', '2020-05-27', '2020-05-28', '2020-05-29', '2020-06-01', '2020-06-02', '2020-06-03', '2020-06-04', '2020-06-05', '2020-06-08', '2020-06-09', '2020-06-10', '2020-06-12', '2020-06-15', '2020-06-16', '2020-06-17', '2020-06-18', '2020-06-19'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Data', freq=None)`

I tried to use calendar.weekday to assing weekday to every row:

`calendar.weekday(df.index.year, df.index.month, df.index.day)`

but I've got an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: We need more of your code.

Comment: I've only loaded data with:

df = pd.read_excel(r'\Data.xlsx', index_col = 'Data')

And after that I tried to use calendar.weekday()

Comment: It is a [duplicate of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10062954/7109869). However, [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62752444/7109869) may help you achieve what you want.