# How to split by weekly and get the count by agent?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a three-month sales data set. I need to get the sales total count by week wise and group by an agent. and want to get daily standard division by the agent in sperate table

```
Agent District Agent_type  Date          Device
12    abc        br         01/02/2020    4233     
12    abc        br         01/02/2020    4123     
12    abc        br         03/02/2020    4314
12    abc        br         05/02/2020    4134
12    abc        br         19/02/2020    5341
12    abc        br         19/02/2020    52141
12    abc        br         19/02/2020    12141
12    abc        br         26/02/2020    4224
12    abc        br         28/02/2020    9563
12    abc        br         05/03/2020    0953
12    abc        br         10/03/2020    1212
12    abc        br         15/03/2020    4309
12    abc        br         02/03/2020    4200
12    abc        br         30/03/2020    4299
12    abc        br         01/04/2020    4211
12    abc        br         10/04/2020    2200
12    abc        br         19/04/2020    3300
12    abc        br         29/04/2020    3222
12    abc        br         29/04/2020    32222
12    abc        br         29/04/2020    4212
12    abc        br         29/04/2020    20922
12    abc        br         29/04/2020    67822
13    aaa        ae         15/02/2020    22222
13    aaa        ae         29/02/2020    42132
13    aaa        ae         10/02/2020    89022
13    aaa        ae         28/02/2020    31111
13    aaa        ae         28/02/2020    31132
13    aaa        ae         28/02/2020    31867
13    aaa        ae         14/02/2020    91122
```

```
output 
Agent District  Agent_type 1st_week_feb   2nd_week_feb   3rd_week_feb .....   4th_week_apr     
12      abc       br   count           count          count                 count
13      aaa       ae   count           count          count                 count
```

2nd output - daily std by agent

```
Agent  tot_sale   daily_std
12       22         2.40
13        7         1.34
```

Comment: This is not a homework help site. Please show you work and read the help section to learn about how to post questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the day of week given a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/how-do-i-get-the-day-of-week-given-a-date)

Comment: @TennisTechBoy, i knew man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
#convert values to datetimes
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

#get weeks strating by 1 
week = df['Date'].dt.isocalendar().week 
df['Week'] = (week - week.min() + 1)
#lowercase months
df['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%b').str.lower()
print (df)
    Agent       Date  Device  Week Month
0      12 2020-02-01    4233     1   feb
1      12 2020-02-01    4123     1   feb
2      12 2020-02-03    4314     2   feb
3      12 2020-02-05    4134     2   feb
4      12 2020-02-19    5341     4   feb
5      12 2020-02-26    4224     5   feb
6      12 2020-02-28    9563     5   feb
7      12 2020-03-05     953     6   mar
8      12 2020-03-10    1212     7   mar
9      12 2020-03-15    4309     7   mar
10     12 2020-03-02    4200     6   mar
11     12 2020-03-30    4299    10   mar
12     12 2020-04-01    4211    10   apr
13     12 2020-04-10    2200    11   apr
14     12 2020-04-19    3300    12   apr
15     12 2020-04-29    3222    14   apr
16     13 2020-02-15   22222     3   feb
17     13 2020-02-29   42132     5   feb
18     13 2020-03-10   89022     7   mar
19     13 2020-03-28   31111     9   mar
20     13 2020-04-14   91122    12   apr
```

---

```
#if need count rows use crosstab
df1 = pd.crosstab(df['Agent'], [df['Week'], df['Month']])
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_week_{x[1]}')
print (df1)
       1_week_feb  2_week_feb  3_week_feb  4_week_feb  5_week_feb  6_week_mar  \
Agent                                                                           
12              2           2           0           1           2           2   
13              0           0           1           0           1           0   

       7_week_mar  9_week_mar  10_week_apr  10_week_mar  11_week_apr  \
Agent                                                                  
12              2           0            1            1            1   
13              1           1            0            0            0   

       12_week_apr  14_week_apr  
Agent                            
12               1            1  
13               1            0
```

---

```
#if need sum Device column use pivot_table 
df2 = df.pivot_table(index='Agent', 
                     columns=['Week', 'Month'], 
                     values='Device',
                     aggfunc='sum', 
                     fill_value=0)
df2.columns = df2.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_week_{x[1]}')
print (df2)
       1_week_feb  2_week_feb  3_week_feb  4_week_feb  5_week_feb  6_week_mar  \
Agent                                                                           
12           8356        8448           0        5341       13787        5153   
13              0           0       22222           0       42132           0   

       7_week_mar  9_week_mar  10_week_apr  10_week_mar  11_week_apr  \
Agent                                                                  
12           5521           0         4211         4299         2200   
13          89022       31111            0            0            0   

       12_week_apr  14_week_apr  
Agent                            
12            3300         3222  
13           91122            0
```

EDIT: Thank you @Henry Yik for pointed another way for count weeks by days:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
df['Week'] = (df["Date"].dt.day-1)//7+1
df['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%b').str.lower()
print (df)
    Agent       Date  Device  Week Month
0      12 2020-02-01    4233     1   feb
1      12 2020-02-01    4123     1   feb
2      12 2020-02-03    4314     1   feb
3      12 2020-02-05    4134     1   feb
4      12 2020-02-19    5341     3   feb
5      12 2020-02-26    4224     4   feb
6      12 2020-02-28    9563     4   feb
7      12 2020-03-05     953     1   mar
8      12 2020-03-10    1212     2   mar
9      12 2020-03-15    4309     3   mar
10     12 2020-03-02    4200     1   mar
11     12 2020-03-30    4299     5   mar
12     12 2020-04-01    4211     1   apr
13     12 2020-04-10    2200     2   apr
14     12 2020-04-19    3300     3   apr
15     12 2020-04-29    3222     5   apr
16     13 2020-02-15   22222     3   feb
17     13 2020-02-29   42132     5   feb
18     13 2020-03-10   89022     2   mar
19     13 2020-03-28   31111     4   mar
20     13 2020-04-14   91122     2   apr
```

Comment: I think OP wants number of week per month, something like `(df["Date"].dt.day-1)//7+1`.

Comment: @jezrael if i want to add another column called 'agent district' as well then how to change this code   df1 = pd.crosstab(df['Agent'], [df['Week'], df['Month']])
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_week_{x[1]}')
print (df1)

Comment: @jezrael could you plz support

Comment: @ShulazShan- @ShulazShan - I got it, change `df1 = pd.crosstab(df['Agent'], [df['Week'], df['Month']])
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_week_{x[1]}')` to `df1 = pd.crosstab([df['Agent'], df['District'], df['Agent_type']], [df['Week'], df['Month']])
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_week_{x[1]}') df = df.reset_index()`

Comment: @jezrael, if i want to get the agent's daily sale stand division, how can code? i try this aug_sales.groupby("ACT_ACTDEVICE").apply(np.std) but not sure whether is correct or not?

Comment: @ShulazShan - It seems correct, do you need `ddof=1` or `ddof=0` ?

Comment: aug_sales.groupby("Agent").apply(np.std) sry not "ACT_ACTDEVICE". ddof mean?

Comment: @ShulazShan - it is degree of freedom, `np.std` is by default `0` in pandas `std` is default 1

Comment: i edited my question above. how can i get the second table as i mention above

Comment: @ShulazShan - do you think `aug_sales.groupby("ACT_ACTDEVICE").agg(['size', np.std]).rested_index()` ?

Comment: how can i get "2nd output - daily std by agent" as i mentioned above. if run "aug_sales.groupby("ACT_ACTDEVICE").agg(['size', np.std]).rested_index()" this i am getting std for device colum as well

Comment: Yop, `aug_sales.groupby("Agent")['ACT_ACTDEVICE'].agg(['size', np.std]).rested_index()`

Comment: @jezrael, if i want to get  mean as well, how to modify above code

Comment: `aug_sales.groupby("Agent")['ACT_ACTDEVICE'].agg(['size', np.std, 'mean']).rested_index() `

Comment: @jezrael i think we need to consider the date column to get daily std to know? here we considering ACT_ACTDEVICE. i am trying to get each agent daily std

Comment: @ShulazShan - Unfortnately not understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223008/discussion-between-shulaz-shan-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that *Date* column has been converted to *datetime*, you can do your
task in the following one-liner:

```
df.groupby(['Agent', pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='W-MON', closed='left',
    label='left')]).count().unstack(level=1, fill_value=0)
```

For your data sample the result is:

```
          Device                                                         
Date  2020-01-27 2020-02-03 2020-02-17 2020-02-24 2020-03-02 2020-03-09  2020-03-30 2020-04-06 2020-04-13 2020-04-27 2020-02-10 2020-03-23
Agent                                                                                                                                      
12             2          2          1          2          2          2           2          1          1          1          0          0 
13             0          0          0          1          0          1           0          0          1          0          1          1
```

​The column name is from the date of a Monday "opening" the week.