# Python datetime if week day ... do

Tags: python, datetime, days, weekday

I will make a python script that say me the correct weekday.
This is what i imagine:

```
def wishMe():

hour = datetime.datetime.now().hour
if hour >= 0 and hour < 12:
    os.system("say Good Morning")
elif hour >= 12 and hour < 18:
    os.system("say Good Afternoon")
else:
    os.system("say Good Evening")

wishMe()
```

But with weekdays.

```
if day >= Monday:
    os.system("say It's Monday")
if day >= Tuesday:
    os.system("say It's Tuesday")
```

.....

I now there's a simpler way.
Like this:

```
  day = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%A')
  print(day)
```

But later i will change it a little bit.

I hope anybody can help me. (and understand what i mean!)

Comment: What do you mean `But later i will change it a little bit.`?

Comment: See [date.workday()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday) which returns the day of the week as an integer, where Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the day of week given a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/how-do-i-get-the-day-of-week-given-a-date)

Answer (score 1):

You could use string manipulation to combine the output of strftime with the code-segment above. For instance, **f-strings** to combine the say "It's Tuesday" and output of strftime.

For example: `os.system(f"say It is {day}")`. Note the f in front of the string denoting that it is a f-string. The curly braces are used to insert values from your program into the string.

You can find more information about f-strings here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Note that the command you are passing to os.system is not compatible across different operating systems. The utility "say" exists in Mac OS, but not Windows and Linux. Also *special characters like ' can cause trouble when executed in the shell* by os.system.

In addition to strftime there are two functions in the datetime-library called weekday and isoweekday. From the docs:

> datetime.weekday()
>
> Return the day of the week as an integer, where Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6. The same as self.date().weekday(). See also isoweekdatetimeday().
>
> datetime.isoweekday()
>
> Return the day of the week as an integer, where Mondatetimeday is 1 and Sunday is 7. The same as self.date().isoweekday(). See also weekday(),

Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.weekday

You could use these to switch based on numbers, or simply do your if/else statements by string-comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```py
("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday")[datetime.datetime.now().weekday()]
```

`datetime.datetime.now()` will give the date and `.weekday()` will give the weekday from 0 to 6, then use that as an index for a tuple with the days

Comment: what's wrong with `datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%A')`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, add a for loop and a list with the days of the week. Just go through them.

```
def day():

    week_days = ["Monday","Tuesday","Weednsday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]
    for day in week_days:
        tday = date.today()
        d1 = tday.strftime("%A")
        print(f"Today is {d1}")
    
day()
```

The output (for today atleast):  "Today is Sunday"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @OneCricketeer That's true, sorry about that.

Comment: Now you're never using `day` loop variable. It'd print the same thing 7 times

Comment: @OneCricketeer and come to think about it, you don't really need a "for" loop.