# How to find the day of a particular date using user-defined variables in python

Tags: python

Im a complete noob in python and coding in general.... I was making a program to calculate the date and day of the next day of the week.... Here, a is the day of the month, b is the month c is the year d is the day of the week. And I wanted to know if we could leverage this to generate the date of a given day without having to enter the present day?

Comment: Can you provide an example input and expected output? Do you mean to find the date that is x days from today?

Comment: Its more of the particular day of a random date... for example the 10th of may of 2021 which was on a Monday.... I need it to accept the inputs and display that its Monday

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/9847213/4046632

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import datetime

a = int(input('Enter a day: '))                          # 10
b = int(input('Enter a month: '))                        # 5
c = int(input('Enter a year: '))                         # 2021

d = datetime.datetime(c, b, a).weekday()                 # 0

days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
print(f'{a}/{b}/{c} - {days[d]}')                        # 10/5/2021 - Mon
```

Output:

```
Enter a day: 10
Enter a month: 5
Enter a year: 2021
10/5/2021 - Mon
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you're asking, but if you want to get the weekday (Monday/Tuesday/etc..) from any given date, you could use the variables to construct a `date` object. You can get the weekday from that as an integer 0-6 with the `weekday()` method or you could print the weekday name using the `strftime()` method.

Example:

```py
import datetime

# day
a = 23
# month
b = 6
# year
c = 2022
input_day = datetime.date(day=a, month=b, year=c)

d = input_day.weekday()
print(d)
# Output: 3

d = input_day.strftime('%A')
print(d)
# Output: 'Thursday'
```

For more info: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects