# Calculating day of week from month, year and day and adding it as a column in my dataset

Tags: python, csv, dayofweek

I have dataset as below:
[image]

I tried to calculate the day of the week using year, month and day, but got error as follows:

[image]

[image]
Can someone please help me out to code this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the day of week given a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/how-do-i-get-the-day-of-week-given-a-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series.dt.day_name`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day_name.html).

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [datetime.datetime(2021,1,1),
                            datetime.datetime(2021,4,1),
                            datetime.datetime(2021,5,1),
                            datetime.datetime(2022,3,1),
                            datetime.datetime(2022,3,31)
                           ]})

df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month
df['day'] = df['date'].dt.day
```

Method 1: using the datetime values.

```
df['date'].dt.day_name()
>>>
0      Friday
1    Thursday
2    Saturday
3     Tuesday
4    Thursday
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Method 2: using the year, month, and day values.

```
pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day']]).dt.day_name()
>>>
0      Friday
1    Thursday
2    Saturday
3     Tuesday
4    Thursday
dtype: object
```